# Why is my /etc/hosts file not being read?

Tags: hosts, ansible

My `/etc/hosts` file looks like this:

```
# Your system has configured 'manage_etc_hosts' as True.
# As a result, if you wish for changes to this file to persist
# then you will need to either
# a.) make changes to the master file in /etc/cloud/templates/hosts.tmpl
# b.) change or remove the value of 'manage_etc_hosts' in
#     /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg or cloud-config from user-data
127.0.1.1 ansible-server ansible-server
127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts

node1 0.0.0.0
node2 0.0.0.0
```

I have added the `node1` and `node2` and naturally the IP `0.0.0.0` is replaced by the IP of the node.

I would assume this works perfectly fine, however it doesn't. I thought SSH simply ignores the `hosts` file:

```
root@ansible-server:~# ssh root@node1
ssh: Could not resolve hostname node1: Name or service not known
root@ansible-server:~# ssh root@node2
ssh: Could not resolve hostname node2: Name or service not known
```

However, I can't ping these servers by their name either:

```
root@ansible-server:~# ping node1
ping: unknown host node1
root@ansible-server:~# ping node2
ping: unknown host node2
```

It is pretty clear I'm doing something really stupid here... but what?

Additional information: this server runs Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS and is hosted on DigitalOcean. The server this is occurring on an Ansible server.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The format of lines in `/etc/hosts` is address first and name(s) second

```
0.0.0.0 node1 
0.0.0.0 node2 
192.168.1.1 myroutermaybe
8.8.8.8 googledns # in case DNS doesn't work for DNS???
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

or where several names map to the same address

```
0.0.0.0 node1 node2 node3 stitch626
```

ADDED, thanks to reminder by fpmurphy1:

The first name (if more than one) is used as the canonical or "official" name for `gethostbyaddr` etc, so if you have a domain name assigned to this machine/address it is usually clearest and most useful to put the Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN) as the first name.

Answer (score 0):

> Asked 7 years, 5 months ago
>
> Why is my /etc/hosts file not being read?

look at `/etc/nsswitch.conf`

this line

```
hosts:      files dns myhostname
```

if it doesn't have `files` there then it definitely will not be read; if `files` doesn't come first then whatever comes first will be used first and can give the impression that your `/etc/hosts` file is not being read because whatever was found in whatever else before it got to the *hosts* file.

my example was taken from RHEL 7.9.  `files` almost always comes first, at least by default from a clean linux install.  But this can and will be changed when linux is configured for whatever and wherever it is being used.